# Why hover in plotly barchart does not work?

Tags: r, hover, plotly

I've got data like this ...

```
# rok miesiac   ile kwartal miesiac2 kwartal2 miesiac3 limit serwis    typ  ile2 ile_proc    lp
# (dbl)   (dbl) (dbl)   (dbl)    (chr)   (fctr)    (chr) (dbl)  (chr)  (chr) (dbl)    (dbl) (dbl)
# 1  2017       1  31.5       1        1  Q1 2017  Styczeń     0  Sport wizyty  32.5       97     1
# 2  2017       2   1.0       1        2  Q1 2017     Luty     0  Sport wizyty  32.5        3     1
```

... and I try to draw this plot from `plotly` library ...

```
plot_ly(tab, 
        x = ~lp, 
        y = ~ile, 
        color = ~miesiac2, 
        type = "bar", 
        text = ~miesiac3,
        hoverinfo = "text")
```

... and everything is ok but hover. It does not work and I have no idea why. What is curious when I have the same format of data but a bit 'longer', everything works.

I have no idea where the problem is. I hope you do!

Simple data:

```
structure(list(rok = c(2017, 2017), miesiac = c(1, 2), ile = c(31.5, 
1), kwartal = c(1, 1), miesiac2 = c("1", "2"), kwartal2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L), .Label = "Q1 2017", class = "factor"), miesiac3 = c("Styczeń", 
"Luty"), limit = c(97, 97), serwis = c("Sport", "Sport"), typ = c("wizyty", 
"wizyty"), ile2 = c(32.5, 32.5), ile_proc = c(97, 3), lp = c(1, 
1)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("rok", "miesiac", "ile", 
"kwartal", "miesiac2", "kwartal2", "miesiac3", "limit", "serwis", 
"typ", "ile2", "ile_proc", "lp"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

'Longer' data:

```
structure(list(rok = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2017, 2017), miesiac = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 1, 2), ile = c(80.1, 87.5, 159, 104, 125.3, 74.2, 84.9, 74.4, 
75.3, 81.8, 2.4), kwartal = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1
), miesiac2 = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", 
"1", "2"), kwartal2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Q2 2016", "Q3 2016", "Q4 2016", 
"Q1 2017"), class = "factor"), miesiac3 = c("Kwiecień", "Maj", 
"Czerwiec", "Lipiec", "Sierpień", "Wrzesień", "Październik", 
"Listopad", "Grudzień", "Styczeń", "Luty"), limit = c(308, 308, 
308, 300, 300, 300, 245, 245, 245, 244, 244), serwis = c("Sport", 
"Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", 
"Sport", "Sport", "Sport"), typ = c("odslony", "odslony", "odslony", 
"odslony", "odslony", "odslony", "odslony", "odslony", "odslony", 
"odslony", "odslony"), ile2 = c(326.6, 326.6, 326.6, 303.5, 303.5, 
303.5, 234.6, 234.6, 234.6, 84.2, 84.2), ile_proc = c(25, 27, 
49, 34, 41, 24, 36, 32, 32, 97, 3), lp = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 4)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("rok", "miesiac", 
"ile", "kwartal", "miesiac2", "kwartal2", "miesiac3", "limit", 
"serwis", "typ", "ile2", "ile_proc", "lp"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: For me it also doesn't work. Maybe version related?! I'am using plotly version 4.5.6. Ok, there was a comment from somebody that it worked for him/her.

Comment: I've got `plotly 4.5.6` too.

Comment: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/864

Answer (score 0):

The plotting works for me, although I do get a warning

```
Warning message:
In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
  minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels
```

This is just a warning and can in this case be ignored. For the curious, it originates from `RColorBrewer` and can be avoided by manually specifying the colors.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
# display.brewer.all() # see all the palettes

# generate colors beforehand - same warning. extract only first two
cols <- brewer.pal(n = 2, name = "Set2")[1:2]

plot_ly(xyshort, 
        x = ~lp, 
        y = ~ile, 
        color = ~miesiac2,
        colors = cols, # explicitly name colors
        type = "bar", 
        text = ~miesiac3,
        hoverinfo = "text")
```

R 3.3.2 on Windows 7 and `plotly_4.5.6`.

Comment: to be complete. I also use R 3.3.2, but on Ubuntu 16.04 and using RStudio 1.0.136

Comment: I've got different version of `R` (`3.3.1`) but I don't think it's problem with `R` version... Any other ideas?

Comment: I've updated my `R` to `3.3.2` to be sure. I also work on `Windows 7` with `plotly_4.5.6` and hover still does not work...

Comment: @Marta ugh, I have to apologize, I did not read your question well enough. Yes, the hover doesn't work for two cases either. It also doesn't work if I wrap a comparable `ggplot` object into `ggplotly`. I will file a [bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/868).